# Can an application event be handled by a lightning component whose body isn't rendered?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

I have a component that receives an app event to indicate if it should be made visible or not. I'm firing this app event from another component on the page.

The receiving component show only show upon receiving the app event with a particular value for the `visible` attribute. I'm hiding the content of the receiving component using this:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.visible}">...</aura:if>
```

However, if `v.visible` is `false` by default, the app event is not received (or handled). If the `v.visible` is `true` by default (and some markup is initially rendered), the app event is received and handled.

It seems that some content must be outputted on the or the app event is ignored/not handled.

Is this expected behavior?

Are there any patterns or work arounds to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: can you show full relevant code in receiving component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior. `aura:if` actually physically removes the component from the DOM/component hierarchy, and therefore it cannot receive events while not rendered. Instead, use `class="slds-hide"` if you want to hide a component that can still receive events.